# No qualifying bean of type SimpleDiscoveryClient

Tags: spring, load-balancing, spring-cloud

everyone!

I want to use SimpleDiscoveryClient from spring loadbalancer without any service registry to get a host for REST request using configs of service instances in my application.yaml file,  but I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I have dependency:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

My application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: mp-investment-wiremock
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            mp-investment-int-nsd:
              - uri: http://localhost:8080
```

What am I doing wrong?
I suppose it because SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration was not tiggered, but why? Maybe I missed something...

Comment: Can you just try using `DiscoveryClient`? If there's no other implementation (like eureka) it will just be the simple one

Comment: Strange, I thought I tried using DiscoveryClient and it didn't work yesterday...
But now I works! Thank you very much!